# ajax requested page not working correctly

Tags: php, ajax

When am trying to request page with ajax it cause php error that classes am calling in these pages not found in these pages although am called all classes in my main php file (index.php) , it seems that ajax calling requested page directly , how can i solve this problem ?

sorry for my bad english

Comment: please share you code sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly how ajax works - it loads the page as if you had visited it directly.
You could solve it by writing your classes in a separate php file, then including that file at the top of both index.php and your other pages.

Comment: and this will not cause any php error ? i mean  like this classes will be called 2 times one in index.php file and other one in the other pages which they are included by index file

Comment: You can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php to test first if one of the functions in that separate file exists - if not, go ahead & include the file.